# Método reverse retorna None

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Estou aplicando o método `reverse` em uma lista e a mesma retorna `None`.

Ex.

```
teste = ['audi', 'subaru', 'fiat', 'ford']
print(teste.reverse())
```

> None

Answer (score 6):

Sempre que estiver na duvida consulte a documentação!

Atente na documentação para o [`reverse`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html):

> list.reverse()
>
> Reverse the elements of the list in place.

Que traduzido significa: inverte os elementos diretamente na lista. Mas não diz que retorna alguma coisa, por isso não retorna nada. A documentação é sempre clara nos retornos indicando qual é sempre que existe um. Veja o do `count` por exemplo:

> list.count(x)
>
> Return the number of times x appears in the list.

No código que tem o mais natural é fazer como o @Maniero mostrou em que faz `reverse` e depois utiliza a lista após ela ter sido invertida. Se apenas necessitar da lista invertida para uma operação, e que não seja permanente pode faze-lo com *slicing* e *step* negativo:

```
>>> teste = ['audi', 'subaru', 'fiat', 'ford']
>>> print(teste[::-1])
['ford', 'fiat', 'subaru', 'audi']
```

Agora relembro que isto é ligeiramente diferente do que tem na pergunta pois neste meu exemplo a lista não foi invertida, apenas utilizei a inversão da lista no `print`, mas a lista original mantem-se igual. Em muitos cenários isto serve para o objetivo, mas noutros pode não servir.

Answer (score 5):

Assim funciona:

```
teste = ['audi', 'subaru', 'fiat', 'ford']
teste.reverse()
print(teste)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/5GQZIo). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/qdmkscpq-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Collection/ReverseList2.py).

A função `reverse()` não devolve uma nova lista ajustada para o que quer, ela manipula a lista atual e devolve nada mesmo, a operação é realizada direto no objeto em questão. Depois você manda imprimir o objeto e sair tudo ok.

Se quiser mesmo que retorne algo para uso direto deve usar a função [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted). Ela é útil se só precisa uma vez assim, ou se precisa que não mexa no original. Se usar esta função pode ser útil gravar em uma variável para posterior utilização. Ela ocupará memória extra. O mesmo pode ser dito do `reversed()` que é mais complicado de usar, eu nem iria por este caminho.

Comment: No caso do `list.reverse` tem o [`reversed(list)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed)

Answer (score 5):

O método [`list.reverse`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists), assim como o `list.sort`, funcionam *in-place*, ou seja, eles alteram a lista original ao invés de retornar uma cópia alterada.

Se você não quer alterar a lista original você pode usar as funções [`reversed()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) e [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) que têm a mesma função porém retornam um [`iterator`](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator), sem alterar a lista original.

Você pode usar o iterador caso não precise ler os valores mais do que uma vez, porém se precisar pode-se converter o iterador para um `list` usando `teste = list(iterador)`. Pode ser menos performático dependendo do tamanho da lista revertida, mas para listas pequenas não tem grande impacto.

```py
teste = ['audi', 'subaru', 'fiat', 'ford']

rev_iterator = reversed(teste) # Iterator que itera a lista de trás pra frente
rev = list(rev_iterator)       # consumindo o iterator e atribuindo a uma lista

print(rev_iterator)  # <list_reverseiterator object at 0x7fdd5beea6a0>
print(rev)           # ['ford', 'fiat', 'subaru', 'audi']
```

[Repl.it do código funcionando](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/AdmiredFullScience)

Answer (score 1):

Meu amigo,
sua pergunta é antiga, mas como muita gente ainda tem dúvida, vou responder com dois métodos diferentes para o python 3:

```
teste = ['audi', 'subaru', 'fiat', 'ford']

print(sorted(teste, reverse=True))
```

ou

```
print(lista.sort(reverse=True)
```

lembrando que o sort salva a lista modificada e o sorted não, ok?

```
knoppix@Microknoppix:~$ python3 $a
['subaru', 'ford', 'fiat', 'audi']
```

Answer (score 0):

Assim funciona meu caro:

```
def lista_reversa(x):
        x.reverse()
        return x

lista = ["a", "b", "c"]
lista = lista_reversa(lista)
print(lista) # ['c', 'b', 'a']
```