# O que está errado no python abaixo? Alguma sugestão de outra solução?

Tags: python, python-3.x, revisão-de-código

Problema: tendo uma matriz 5×5 preenchida com valores aleatórios (reais) entre 0 e 99, mostre qual é o segundo maior valor existente na matriz.

Não pode usar numpy ou similares.

Minha solução:

```
n=2
def constroi_matriz(n):
    import random
    matriz =[[]]
    linha =[]
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            num = random.randint(0,99)
            linha.append(num)
        matriz.append(linha)
        linha =[]
    matriz.pop(0)#excluir a posicao que contem []
    return matriz


def segundo_maior(matriz):
 maior = max(max(matriz))
 for i in range(len(matriz)):
     for j in range(len(matriz)):
         if matriz[i][j] == maior:
             matriz[i].remove(maior)
             print(matriz)




 return max(max(matriz))

matriz = constroi_matriz(2)
print(f"A matriz é {matriz}")
print(f"O segundo maior é: {segundo_maior(matriz)}")
```

Não sei porque às vezes recebo erro de "builtins.IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: Já fez o [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/5878) do seu código? Tem várias coisas estranhas nele: 1) não tem porque iniciar `matriz` com uma lista vazia sendo que depois irá removê-la; 2) `max(max(matriz))` não retornará o maior valor da matriz; 3) você define a função `segundo_maior` e nunca a chama; 4) na função `segundo_maior` você exclui elementos da matriz, o que não faz muito sentido;

Comment: Woss: sim. e nao consegui descobrir o que está errado...

Comment: Consegue nos mostrar o resultado do seu teste de mesa?

Comment: @Woss: eu fiz tentando executar no papel e nao descobri o erro na minha lógica!

Comment: @Woss: eu tinha esquecido de colocar as chamadas das funções. Editei a pergunta!

Comment: Recomendo começar estudando como [Encontrar o maior e menor elemento de uma matriz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/364151/5878); para o segundo maior, basta replicar a mesma lóigca do maior adicionando a condição que o segundo maior não pode ser maior que o próprio maior. Sobre como criar uma matriz, veja [Como criar uma matriz em python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/205528/5878)

Answer (score 2):

## TL;DR

Conhecendo um pouco os módulos que o Python disponibiliza e algumas funcionalidade da linguagem você pode fazer isso de maneira mais simples:

```
from random import randint
from itertools import chain


def constroi_matriz(m, n, min_num=0, max_num=99):
    return [ 
        [randint(min_num, max_num) for _ in range(m)]
        for _ in range(n)
    ]


def segundo_maior(matriz):
    return sorted(chain.from_iterable(matriz))[-2]


matriz = constroi_matriz(5, 5)

print(matriz)
print(segundo_maior(matriz))
```

<sup>Veja rodando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/SOPt-423790-6333)</sup>

---

## Explicação

Na função `constroi_matriz` utilizei [*list comprehensions*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) para criar a matriz, onde:

```
matriz = [ 
    [randint(min_num, max_num) for _ in range(m)]
    for _ in range(n)
]
```

Seria equivalente a:

```
matriz = []
for i in range(m):
    matriz.append([])
    for j in range(n):
        matriz[i].append(j)
```

<sup>**PS**: Na [documentação de *list comprehensions*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) você verá que podem-se repetir N `for` para criar quantas dimensões da matriz você quiser.</sup>

Já na função `segundo_maior` eu sigo uma regra mais simples:

1. Transformo a matriz em uma lista usando [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable).
   Ex.:

   ```
   from itertools import chain

   matriz = [[10, 20, 30], [5, 50, 500]]
   lista = chain.from_iterable(matriz)
   print(lista)
   # [10, 20, 30, 5, 50, 500]
   ```
2. Ordeno esta lista usando a função [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted).
   Ex.:

   ```
   lista = [10, 20, 30, 5, 50, 500]
   ordenada = sorted(lista)
   print(ordenada)
   # [5, 10, 20, 30, 50, 500]
   ```

   <sup>**OBS**.: [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) retorna uma nova lista com os dados ordenados, mantendo a lista original. Se você quer sobrescrever a lista original você deve usar [`list.sort()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists). Perguntas relacionadas: ["Método “sort” retornando apenas “None”, qual o motivo?"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/375211/6333) e ["Método reverse retorna None"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/328919/6333).</sup>
3. Pego o penúltimo item da lista ordenada, ou seja, o segundo maior.
   Ex.:

   ```
   ordenada = [5, 10, 20, 30, 50, 500]
   print(ordenada[-2])
   # 50
   ```

Answer (score 1):

seu problema esta nesta linha, ela pode alterar o comprimento da lista mas como esta dentro de uma codição não é sempre que ela vai fazer esta alteração que causa o problema.

```
matriz[i].remove(maior)
```

fiz algumas mudanças,como sugestão

```
n=2
def constroi_matriz(n):
    import random
    matriz =[] 
    for i in range(n):
        linha =[] 
        for j in range(n):
            num = random.randint(0,99)
            linha.append(num)
        matriz.append(linha)
    return matriz


def segundo_maior(matriz):
    maior = []
    for i in matriz:
        maior.extend(i)
    maior.sort()
    return maior[-2]

matriz = constroi_matriz(n)
print('A matriz é', *matriz, sep='\n')
print(f"O segundo maior é: {segundo_maior(matriz)}")
```

nesse segundo codigo seria uma aproximação mais preguiçosa

```
from random import randint
from itertools import chain

n=2

def constroi_matriz(n):
    matriz =[[randint(0, 99) for x in range(n)]
            for y in range(n)]
    return matriz


def segundo_maior(matriz):
    lista = [x for x in chain(*matriz)]
    lista = sorted(set(lista))

    if len(lista) > 1:
        return lista[-2]
    return lista[0]

matriz = constroi_matriz(n)
print('A matriz é', *matriz, sep='\n')
print(f"O segundo maior é: {segundo_maior(matriz)}")  insira o código aqui
```

nesse caso eu faço algumas conversões, de **list** para **set** que retira todas as igualdades, e de volta para **list** para organizar e pegar a  posição

Comment: Alguma forma mais simples de fazer do que a que eu tentei?

Comment: Eu percebi que o código falha qdo recebe matriz com valores repetido: A matriz é
[1, 1]
[2, 2]
O segundo maior é: 2